# Putting words in alphabetical order

Tags: word-property

I have tried to put these words in alphabetical order. Can you find what is wrong with my ordering? What is the correct order?

> alien, arson, beetle, canine, cucumber, dealer, eastern, effort, elevate, eminent, enter, estimate, eunuch, expert, island, jailbird, jeans, open, peachy, seaman, teenager, veto, wiring, zebra

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the 'alphabetical' order you're actually looking for is:

> alien, beetle, seaman, dealer, eastern, effort, jeans, island, jailbird, canine, elevate, eminent, enter, open, peachy, cucumber, arson, estimate, teenager, eunuch, veto, expert, wiring, zebra

Since:

> The first syllable (or thereabouts) of these words sounds like a letter of the English alphabet:
>
>  **A**lien, **BEE**tle, **SEA**man, **DEA**ler, **EA**stern, **EFF**ort, **JEA**ns, **I**sland, **JAI**lbird, **CA**nine, **EL**evate, **EM**inent, **EN**ter, **O**pen, **PEA**chy, **CU**cumber, **AR**son, **ES**timate, **TEE**nager, **EU**nuch, **VE**to, **EX**pert, **WI**ring, **ZE**bra
>
>  Here, all letters of the English alphabet with the exception of 'H' and 'W' are represented.  Good luck finding a dictionary which will list them in this way! ;-)

Comment: "Zebra" only works for Americans.  The rest of the world pronounces it "Zed".

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Indeed - perhaps I should have specified *American*-English! (And it's a good job there's no 'H' word here - I wouldn't have wanted to start the aitch/haitch fires burning...!)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain sure, but I've also heard it pronounced "zeh-bra", particularly by non-American English speakers

Comment: If you're willing to stretch the pronunciation a little, then "etching" could be a plausible "H" word.  I can't think of a "W", though.

Comment: 'uudecode'. OK maybe a slight stretch...